# How to decode incorrectly encoded data in mysql

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have mysql table with "latin1_swedish_ci" collation. The table is used to store strings in multiple languages (russian, english, latvian). As a result, the strings stored in the table are incorrectly encoded.
For example: `Двери` is stored as `Ð”Ð²ÐµÑ€Ð¸`

I spent hours trying to find coding, which would allow me to properly store strings in new table with "utf8_general_ci" collation.

I used python to guess the decoding for the incorrect strings. I ran through tens of different encodings and the closest I got was
`print "Двери".decode("latin1")`
gives me `ÐÐ²ÐµÑÐ¸`, which is close but not exactly `Ð”Ð²ÐµÑ€Ð¸`

I was wondering if there are some variations in latin1 encoding, which would give me a proper encoding? And I would greatly appreciate if someone would suggest a way how to resolve similar problems in general?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When the coding used in the stored data doesn't match the coding defined for the column, you can first switch to a binary type, then back to the text type with the appropriate character set. For example, after backing up your database,

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY col varbinary(...);
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY col varchar(...) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Make sure your client also uses UTF8 for its connection to the server by (e.g.) issuing a `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` command.

See also:

- [Changing character sets with ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html#id814177) (from the MySQL manual, §12.1.7. ALTER TABLE Syntax)
- [Converting Character Sets](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/17/converting-character-sets/)
- [Turning MySQL data in latin1 to utf8](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html)
- [Converting Database Character Sets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets)

Answer (score 0):

It's the very-similar-yet-different **CP1252**.

```
>>> print u'Ð”Ð²ÐµÑ€Ð¸'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
Двери
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ignacio. If I have a dump file and I want to perform the transformation you showed me on the whole file, how would I do that?

Comment: Depends on the charset used in the dump. If it's CP1252 then just read it as UTF-8 instead. If it's UTF-8 then just decode as UTF-8, encode as CP1252, then read it in as UTF-8.

Comment: I ran 'file dump.sql' to make sure that utf8 is used in the dump. after that I ran 'iconv -f utf8 -t cp1252 dump.sql'.
After successfully converting first few lines, iconv chokes: 'iconv: dump.sql:7:32: cannot convert'. Is it possible that some of the characters are corrupted, i.e. cant be properly converted from cp1252?

Comment: Yes, it may be entirely possible that the data within the database has been goofed around enough for it to actually be using multiple encodings. You will have to handle it line by line in that case.

Comment: Ignacio, so the only way to resolve this is just basically guessing the set of encodings, which could return correct string?
But how does browser handles this? if I just run a query and output the result, my web page (with charset set to utf8) renders perfectly fine.

Comment: Not for *everything* in the database. The things that don't, are in a different encoding.

Comment: Do you have ideas what similar codings could be used (other than cp1252)?
For string `Ð¿ÐµÐ½Ð¾Ð¿Ð»Ð°ÑÑ‚Ð¾Ð²Ñ‹Ðµ Ð¿Ð¾Ñ‚Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ñ‡Ð½Ñ‹Ðµ Ð¿Ð»Ð¸Ñ‚ÐºÐ¸, Ð¸Ð·Ð¾Ð»ÑÑ†Ð¸Ñ, ÐºÐ»ÐµÑ` iconv returns `пенопла?
iconv: categories_dump.sql:1:15: cannot convert` for cp1252 and `пеноплас?
iconv: categories_dump.sql:1:16: cannot convert` for latin1. while it the proper string would be `пенопластовые потолочные плитки, изоляция, клея`

I am getting despaired here, because our database has around 4000 items.

Comment: That one is Latin-1. `>>> print u'пенопластовые потолочные плитки, изоляция, клея'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin1')`
`Ð¿ÐµÐ½Ð¾Ð¿Ð»Ð°ÑÑÐ¾Ð²ÑÐµ Ð¿Ð¾ÑÐ¾Ð»Ð¾ÑÐ½ÑÐµ Ð¿Ð»Ð¸ÑÐºÐ¸, Ð¸Ð·Ð¾Ð»ÑÑÐ¸Ñ, ÐºÐ»ÐµÑ`